# Using find() excluding some elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use find() to find all inputs in a form and change its value to ''. But I also need to exclude 2 inputs, the name of these inputs are: 'data', and 'date'

I tried this (with no success)

**$('#contactForm').find("input[ @name != 'data' ][ @name != 'date' ]").val('');**

Comment: don't forget to accept correct answers by clicking the hollow checkmark to the left of the correct answer! :)

Comment: @Jacob I think he's forgotten!

Answer (score 2):

Use `jQuery`'s [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method:

```
$('#contactForm').find('input').not("[name='data'],[name='date']").val('');
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CBKBy/) example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').each(function(){
 if ( this.name != 'data' && this.name != 'date')
     this.value = '';
});
```